# Finding elements in AngularJS using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, xpath, protractor, automated-tests

I'm writing some automated tests on an AngularJS application. I'm trying to click a button but whatever method I try and use, Selenium refuses to find the element.

```
<div class="row" _ngcontent-c24="">
 <div class="column-12 column-center" _ngcontent-c24="">
  <div class="buttons column-center" _ngcontent-c24="">
   <div class="buttons-container-centred tablet-up" _ngcontent-c35="">
    <div _ngcontent-c35="">
     <kf-button _ngcontent-c35="" btnstyle="secondary no-outline btn-big" _nghost-c8="">
      <button class="secondary no-outline btn-big" _ngcontent-c8="" title="" type="">
       <span _ngcontent-c8="">Use a demo room</span>
   </button>
  </kf-button>
 <span _ngcontent-c35="">Instant access</span>
</div>
```

This is html around the button - button text is "Use a demo room"

I've tried:

```
element(by.xpath(" full path from FirePath ").click()
element(by. buttonText("Use a demo room").click()
element(by.xpath('//span[@ngcontent("Use a demo room"]')).click
```

...to mention a few.

Usual error message stating the element cannot be found once the timeout is reached.

Other similar buttons work fine with a full xpath.

Would be really grateful for advice!

Thanks

David

Comment: Can you try this xpath `"//button[./span='Use a demo room']"`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks for this. Same result I'm afraid! Exact line was element(by.xpath("//button[./span='Use a demo room']")).click();

Comment: @TarunLalwani produced "Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(xpath, //button[./span='Use a demo room'])"

Comment: Okie can you try this `browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//button[./span='Use a demo room']")).click()` and also try another xpath `//span[.='Use a demo room']`. See if any of these help

Comment: If `element(by.buttonText("Use a demo room").click()` fails, it means that the element is still not present once the timeout is reached or that the element is in a frame, in which case you need to switch to it.